# What are logarithms, and what do they do?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Intuitive use of logarithms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35810/intuitive-use-of-logarithms)

My math teacher "taught" us about logarithms today, but he didn't give any useful information. He just that one is supposed to "add" them to create a quadratic equation. He then gave us this example;

$$ \log_4 (x + 4) +  \log_4 (x - 4) $$

He then told us to solve it. This is how he did it.

$$\log_4  (x + 4) + \log_4 (x - 4)$$

$$(x + 4)(x - 4) = 0$$

$$x = -4, 4$$

This does not make a bit of sense to me. What are logarithms for? What do they do? And, most importantly, how would I actually solve this equation?

Comment: I just want to point out, that it is sloppy to say "solve" since 
"$\log_4$(x + 4) + $\log_4$(x - 4)" is technically $not$ an equation.

Comment: Doesn't make a lot of sense to me either.  For one thing, an equation needs to have an $=$ sign, and your first line doesn't. For general information on logarithms, please see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm. (You will want to skip initially the parts of this article that are clearly too advanced.)

Comment: You'll also want to note that $x = -4$ is an extraneous solution since you can't take the logarithm of a negative number in the original equation (in the Reals)

Comment: I know that all of you say it is not right at all, bit this is _exactly_ what he wrote. That is why I am confused. Thanks for all of the help and links!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to solve
$$\log_4{(x-4)} + \log_4{(x+4)} = 0$$ you combine that to
$$\log_4{(x-4)(x+4)} = 0$$ then exponentiate each side by taking
$$4^{\log_4{(x-4)(x+4)}} = 4^0$$ which gives
$$ (x-4)(x+4) = 1 $$ which you can solve using whichever algebraic method you prefer.

You should get $x = -\sqrt{17}, +\sqrt{17}$, but as I noted in my above comment, the negative solution is extraneous.

Comment: These are all "Logarithmic Identities" which you can read about on the wikipedia page.

Comment: Thanks. I think I am beginning to understand this.

Comment: You should use braces in the first equation

Comment: @user3123: thanks, I noticed that after I posted and have fixed it, after frustratingly losing my internet connection in the middle of the edit :p