# Real life applications for logarithms

Tags: soft-question, logarithms, big-list

Can someone please tell me what purposes logarithms have in the everyday world? What non-theoretical applications are they in and when would one use them?

Comment: Most of the answers to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35810/intuitive-use-of-logarithms) apply here. I'm tempted to close as a duplicate.

Comment: Wow! This is probably a duplicate then...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way in which our sense-organs $($eye, ear, etc.$)$ perceive the outside world $($light, sound, etc.$)$ is logarithmic; e.g., if a sound becomes $a^n$ times stronger, we only perceive it as *n* times stronger.

Comment: What's $$a$$ for humans?

Answer (score 4):

You can use it in mortgage calculation. 
If you have a limit value to pay monthly for your house mortgage and if you wonder how many months needs to pay , you need to use logarithm. (It gives you idea about your budget and payment time)

With a fixed rate mortgage (interest is r), the borrower agrees to pay off the loan  P completely at the end of the loan's term, so the amount owed at month N must be zero. For this to happen, the monthly payment c can be obtained from the previous equation to obtain:
$$
\begin{align}
c & {} = \frac{r}{1-(1+r)^{-N}}P
\end{align}
$$

$$ (1+r)^N=\frac{c}{c-rP}$$

$$ (1+r)^N=\frac{c}{c-rP}$$

For example :

You plan to get ${$}100,000$ from bank and  interest rate is $0.15$ and you plan to pay each month $1,000 ,

in this case,

$$ (1+r)^N=\frac{c}{c-rP}$$

$$ (1+0.0015)^N=\frac{1000}{1000-0.0015. 100000}$$

$$ (1.0015)^N=\frac{1000}{1000-0.0015 .100000}\approx1.1764705882352941$$

You need to calculate $N=\log_{1.0015}(1.1764705882352941)=\frac{\log(1.1764705882352941)}{\log (1.0015)}\approx \frac{0.07058107428570726667356900039616}{6.50953.10^{-4}}\approx108.42 months$

It gives you an idea about how many months you need to pay your mortgage payments with your payment budget.
Please see Reference [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-rate_mortgage)  for detailed mortgage formulas

Answer (score 3):

Anywhere you find exponentials you will find logarithms.  For example, if a population (people, animals, bacteria, whatever) is allowed to grow unchecked at a constant rate of reproduction, then the population at time $t$ will be $r^t$ times as large as the initial population.  So the time required for the population to increase by a factor of $k$ is $\log_rk$.

Answer (score 2):

Logarithmic scales such as decibels for sound and the Richter scale for earthquakes.

When I was young, logarithms had an even more practical use: multiplying and dividing numbers.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to design a system to control/command something, a super popular method requires using some diagrams (Bode plots) where the property of logarithms of turning multiplication into addition is very useful.

Answer (score 2):

Some sea shells are quite perfect logarithmic spirals! :)
In nature we have plenty of this!

[image]